# ORA-12516: when accessing another database via link

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, blob

I need to bring some data (blobs) from another database. I created global links to enable bidirectional communication. The links work. When I try to bring some data from tables that have BLOB columns I get intermittently the ORA-12516:

> TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack

Here's what I run to bring BLOBs to my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_MY_TABLE AS 
SELECT * FROM SOME_REMOTE_TABLE_WITH_BLOB_COLUMN@dblink_source;
```

Oracle 11 r2. Blobs have different sizes.

Number of `PROCESSES` is set to 1000 and only half is utilized during the run. Sessions = 1528.

Both source and target are identical in hardware and software including patches.

The links work fine for hundreds of other queries. I checked and they are resolved properly.

Comment: Add the definition of the dblink. If it uses a TNS alias, post what that TNS alias is resolved to. Add the output of `lsnrctl services` from the source system. Add the output of `select * from gv$resource_limit where resource_name in ('sessions', 'processes');` from the source database. Blob, dblink are most likely irrelevant here, sounds just like a typical connecion issue with inadequate free sessions/processes.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are reaching the maximum connections allowed. Make sure that old sessions are being closed properly and try increasing the processes and sessions parameters.